# Store UUID in sqlite manager

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uuid, sqlitemanager

I am a newbie here. I am trying to generate UUIDs using the following code..

```
- (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    //CFUUIDBytes number = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes (theUUID);
    DLog(@"Howwww :%@", theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

I am getting the result in a string as..

```
NSString *result = [self GetUUID];
```

Now the problem is I am unable to store it inside my sqlite database. I am trying to store it in a `VARCHAR` column using the statement

```
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 10, [_idNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Please can anyone help me out here. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that return the UUID as a `NSString`, just save it in the db as a string.

```
- (NSString *)newUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return (NSString *)string;
}
```

If you need a c string:

```
NSString *uuidString = [self newUUID];
const char *uuidCString = [uuidString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: I am saving it in the db as nsstring.. but it is not saving it somehow.. its saving some other value..